# UIImagePickerController modular replacement

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, picasa, flickr, photolibrary

I am looking for a replace to UIImagePickerController that allows custom extensibility for local pictures, public API's like Facebook/Flickr/Tumblr/Picasa/SmugMug, and custom proprietary picture collections (local or abroad).

Solutions I have found so far, and problems with them:

### http://picture.io/photopickerplus

This is almost perfect, except I am forced to use the 3rd party service from getchute.com - what happens if this site goes dark, permanently? And all permissions dialogs list "Chute" as the application name. My app uses the Facebook SDK elsewhere, so I would like to use my existing APP id/key. When I add it via the chute app control panel, I get the Facebook API error "Invalid redirect_uri:Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration". Which I can fix with the Facebook API, however if A. I knew what the URL was (I don't), and B. I really was OK with having a middle man with the API requests (I'm not).

It is also very ARC hostile which is a PITA to get running.

### https://github.com/arturgrigor/AGImagePickerController

Very nice replacement for UIImagePickerController, that includes multi select. No built modularity to support Facebook or other API's.

### https://github.com/jeena/JPImagePickerController

Simple replacement for just UIImagePickerController - doesn't seem to have navigable views. No apparent modularity.

### https://github.com/facebook/three20/

Looks complicated. For obvious reasons won't play well with non-Facebook services.

Comment: Roll your own, it will be faster than dealing with 3rd party...

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mrdavenz/CaptureSessionManager  has example code of to create your own photo picker with AVCamera. You could use this as a starting point.  See the blog at http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1297